# Mixed Logit Model in Zelig (R) -- not running -- not available anymore?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, r-zelig

I am interested in getting first differences from a mixed logit model using the Zelig package. However, I am not able to run a mixed logit model in Zelig. I updated the Zelig package as instructed by the Zelig website.

I ran the mixed logit mode but I got the following error: *Error: logit.mixed is not a supported model type.*

I tried to run the model from the vignette and got the same error:

```
library(Zelig)
data(voteincome)
z.out1 <- zelig(vote ~ education + age + female +tag(1 | state), data=voteincome, model="logit.mixed")
```

I get the following error:
*Error: logit.mixed is not a supported model type.*

Is "logit.mixed" no longer available on Zelig? I am currently using R version 3.5.1 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Replying to this older post in case anyone else is doing this as well. Looks like the instructions here to use the remotes package to download ZeligMultilevel currently work better than devtools::install_github(); I ran into the same dependency problem as the previous user.

Instead, users can use this code, available **[here](https://rdrr.io/github/IQSS/ZeligMultilevel/)**:

```
install.packages("remotes")

remotes::install_github("IQSS/ZeligMultilevel")
```

Just remember to accept the remotes package's suggestion to update all packages. Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `logit.mixed` is no longer supported by the `zelig`-package.

It was implemented in Zelig 4: http://zeligdev.github.io/ , but I can not find it in the [currently supported models](http://docs.zeligproject.org/articles/).

There is, however, a deprecated version of a package called `ZeligMultilevel` up on github [available here](https://github.com/IQSS/ZeligMultilevel).

You can try:

```
devtools::install_github("IQSS/ZeligMultilevel")
```

and then, followed by the [demo](https://github.com/IQSS/ZeligMultilevel/blob/master/demo/demo-logit.mixed.R), you can:

```
library(ZeligMultilevel)


data(voteincome)

z5 <- zlogitmixed$new()
z5
z5$zelig(vote ~ education + age + female + (1 | state),
         data = voteincome)
z5
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran the first two lines of code:
    devtools::install_github("IQSS/ZeligMultilevel")
    library(ZeligMultilevel)
But I got the following error: _Error in library(ZeligMultilevel) : 
  there is no package called ‘ZeligMultilevel’_

Is there anything I missed in the installation process? Thanks again!

Comment: what happened after `install_github` ? You probably have to install the `devtools` package first.

Comment: I figured it out. I installed devtools without a problem. I noticed that install_github asked how many additional packages I wanted to install. There were a few errors for some packages, so I installed those individually. Eventually, install_github("IQSS/ZeligMultilevel") ran smoothly. I was able to do the demo that you linked to. Thanks!

Comment: @saidnone perfect! glad that my answer could help you